# Subject a reserved word in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, social-networking, social-stream

I've built a model called "Subject" in my Rails 3.2 application. I used the scaffold command below.

```
rails g scaffold Subject subject singular:boolean gender:integer subject_masculine subject_feminine subject_neuter language:references --skip-stylesheets
```

The scaffold runs almost to the end, but then gives a mysterious error about the helper:

**The name 'SubjectsHelper' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative and run this generator again.**

I've tried reversing the scaffold and rebuilding. In the end I just built the table and it seems to be working ok. There is no **helpers/subjects_helper.rb** file, but I don't expect to need a helper for this particular model.

I could not find **subject** among any reserved word list, but that in itself was a problem. Another SO post has been raised on this issue.

[List of reserved words in rails *3*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13681409/list-of-reserved-words-in-rails-3)

Why am I getting this error, and can I just ignore it?

**EDIT**

My Gemfile as requested

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'thin'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'pg'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "nested_form"
gem 'thinking-sphinx'
gem 'devise'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'ruby_parser'
gem 'html2haml'
gem 'best_in_place'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog'
gem 'seed_dump'
gem 'bluecloth'
gem 'redcarpet'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'prototype-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'jquery-datatables-rails'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'social_stream'
gem 'rails-footnotes', '>= 3.7.5.rc4', :group => :development

group :development do
  gem 'rails-erd'
  gem 'quiet_assets'
end

gem 'vestal_versions', :git => "git://github.com/futurechimp/vestal_versions.git"
gem 'diffy'
gem 'diffrent'
```

**EDIT2**

As per Philip's suggestion, I ran the **Module.constants** command from the Rails console. Amongst the output, there were two 'subject' values:

```
:SubjectsHelper
:Subject
```

I check several times there is no helper, so I decided to add one. I created the **helpers/subjects_helper.rb** file, with the following code:

```
module SubjectsHelper
end
```

Rails has now rebooted OK. I still don't understand what happened though.

Comment: why do you have a second subject in the the generate command?

Comment: I guess it's used by Rspec

Comment: try **Module.constants.include? :SubjectsHelper**

Comment: Thanks for your comment Evgeniy. I don't really understand what you mean though.

Comment: To answer Sathish's question: the first subject is the class name and the second is a field called subject. I left the string off as it defaults.

Comment: @SeanGeneva Start up rails console and type in "Module.constants..." and see what the result is.

Comment: Thanks for your post Philip. I've added the reponse as Edit2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly say, SubjectsHelper is already provided by Social Stream. See:

https://github.com/ging/social_stream/blob/master/base/app/helpers/subjects_helper.rb

Your solution is working because you are reopening the module, which is a valid action in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I am using the Social Stream gem, which has a subject in the routes.

```
subject_lrdd        /subjects/lrdd/:id(.:format)
```

It must be buried in the engine somewhere.

Comment: It's possible to create a ssubject model; note double 's'